# How to revert to a minimal installation (Ububtu 18.04.1)?

Tags: minimal-install

I did a clean minimal install of Ubuntu 18.04.1, got all my programs and data installed and did a reboot.  It only came up with the non-graphical login prompt.  After trying to fix this a piece at a time I gave in and installed ubuntu-desktop.  That fixed everything, but it also install all the "extra stuff" that isn't part of the minimal install.

I know how to delete the obvious additional programs that are listed as installed, but not how to uninstall anything that may not be visibly obvious. Is there a way to get rid of that extra stuff and just be left with what I would have had with the minimal install?

Comment: You cant the installer installs everything then removes the packages.. you need to remove them manually. Its probably enough to do this from the software center because this cleans the unneeded dependencies.

Comment: Aren't there things installed that don't show up in the software center?  I am thinking of things like programs that a user doesn't directly run.

Comment: There are hidden packages however when these are not needed anymore they will be removed by the update manager or the software center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the list of package names included in the full install but not in the minimal install.  This is how I generated the list.

I did a full install on a vm and ran

```
apt list --installed > onefile
```

Then I installed a minimum install on a VM, ran the command again out to a second file, compared the files and found the ones that are not in the minimum install.

Using this information, you can diff it against your own installed list and decide what packages you want to uninstall using

```
apt-get remove package_name
```

or
    apt-get purge package_name

Here is the list of package names included in the full install but not in the minimal install.

```
aisleriot
baobab
branding-ubuntu
cheese
deja-dup
example-content
gir1.2-rb-3.0
gir1.2-totem-1.0
gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0
gnome-calendar
gnome-mahjongg
gnome-mines
gnome-sudoku
gnome-todo
gnome-todo-common
gnome-video-effects
guile-2.0-libs
hyphen-en-us
libabw-0.1-1
libavahi-ui-gtk3-0
libdmapsharing-3.0-2
libexttextcat-2.0-0
libexttextcat-data
libfreehand-0.1-1
libgnome-games-support-1-3
libgnome-games-support-common
libgnome-todo
libmessaging-menu0
libmhash2
libminiupnpc10
libmwaw-0.3-3
libmythes-1.2-0
libnatpmp1
libneon27-gnutls
liborcus-0.13-0
libpagemaker-0.0-0
libraptor2-0
librasqal3
librdf0
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
libreoffice-base-core
libreoffice-calc
libreoffice-common
libreoffice-core
libreoffice-draw
libreoffice-gnome
libreoffice-gtk3
libreoffice-help-en-us
libreoffice-impress
libreoffice-math
libreoffice-ogltrans
libreoffice-pdfimport
libreoffice-style-breeze
libreoffice-style-galaxy
libreoffice-style-tango
libreoffice-writer
librhythmbox-core10
libtotem0
libvisio-0.1-1
libwpd-0.10-10
libwpg-0.3-3
libwps-0.4-4
libyajl2
mythes-en-us
python3-uno
remmina
remmina-common
remmina-plugin-rdp
remmina-plugin-secret
remmina-plugin-vnc
rhythmbox
rhythmbox-data
rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar
rhythmbox-plugins
shotwell
shotwell-common
simple-scan
thunderbird
thunderbird-gnome-support
thunderbird-locale-en
thunderbird-locale-en-us
totem
totem-common
totem-plugins
transmission-common
transmission-gtk
ubuntu-web-launchers
uno-libs3
ure
usb-creator-gtk
vino
zeitgeist-core
```

Comment: I am going to mark this answered.  I made a shell script using the above list with one line for each package " apt-get --assume-yes --purge autoremove packageName"  This worked fine.  The only strange thing was that GnuCash was removed but I just reinstalled that.